# PUT/PATCH not going through when using postman + express

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I'm trying to update a user's shipping information. I have default data in mongodb that I'm trying to overwrite with a PATCH/PUT. Right now postman hangs indefinitely. The mongoose model has the values, my else{} statement outputs the JSON object to be submitted with no error, but it never goes through. I appreciate any help. 
POSTMAN

`Could not get any response`

app.js

```
app.put('/api/users/:id', (req, res) => {

  User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id },

    {
      fullName: req.body.fullName,
      address1: req.body.address1,
      address2: req.body.address2,
      city: req.body.city,
      state: req.body.state,
      zip: req.body.zip
    }, function (err, docs) {
      if (err) res.json(err);

      else {
       // console.log(docs)
      }
    });
})
```

MODEL

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const shippingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  fullName: { type: String},
  address1: { type: String },
  address2: { type: String },
  city: { type: String },
  state: { type: String},
  zip: { type: String}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Shipping", shippingSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to send a response, so the request never finishes.

```js
app.put('/api/users/:id', (req, res) => {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id },
    {
      fullName: req.body.fullName,
      address1: req.body.address1,
      address2: req.body.address2,
      city: req.body.city,
      state: req.body.state,
      zip: req.body.zip
    }, function (err, docs) {
      if (err) res.json(err);

      else {
        // console.log(docs)

        // don't forget to send a response
        res.json({
          "message": "works!",
        });
      }
    });
})
```